# A question on measurable functions on the interval [0,1]

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Consider the set $[0,1]$ and the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by simply by $f(x)=x$. I believe this function $f$ is measurable isn't it? Where I am getting confused is when I consider the set $(-0.1,0.1)\subset \mathbb{R}$. I belive this is in the Borel algebra $B\left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

The problem is that $f^{-1}\left ((-0.1,0.1  \right ))\nsubseteq [0,1]$, so I don't see how the set $f^{-1}\left ((-0.1,0.1  \right ))$ could be in the the Borel algebra $B([-0.1,0.1])$. But that would mean that we have a set $f^{-1}\left ((-0.1,0.1  \right ))\in B\left ( \mathbb{R} \right )$ that is unmeasurable in $[0,1]$. But that would mean that f is NOT measurable on the set $[0,1]$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a function $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and a set $S\subset B$,$$f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A\,|\,f(a)\in S\}.$$In particular, $f^{-1}(S)\subset A$. So, $f^{-1}\bigl((-0.1,0.1)\bigr)\subset[0,1]$. And, yes, $f$ is measurable.

Comment: I am confused because $f^{-1}\left ( (-0.1,0.1) \right )=\left ( -0.1,0.1 \right )$  and $\left ( -0.1,0.1 \right )\nsubseteq [0,1]$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @RoryCornish Did you read my definition of $f^{-1}(S)$? It turns out that $f^{-1}\bigl((-0.1,0.1)\bigr)=[0,0.1)$.

Comment: Sorry. I just figured it out as you were writing to me. Thanks for that. That makes sense

Comment: @RoryCornish Yes. That is why you wrote that same equality in my previous comment.